# Adding Class Libraries to Solution - Adding Folders to Web Application

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, asp.net-core

I've come across a problem when trying to add multiple .net core class libraries to an already existing .net core web application running on version 1.1. When selecting 'Add > New Project..' and selecting the .Net Core Class Library project type, the class library is added to the solution, but a folder is also created under the web application which I'm finding to be very strange.

If I then go and add another class library, it gets added to the top of the solution which is correct, but another folder is yet again added to the web application.

[image: Class library folder issue]

As there are now two class library folders in the web application, I get errors telling me that I have duplicate files in my web app project.

[image]

I'm using a start template from this [blog](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2016/05/02/angular2-react-knockout-apps-on-aspnet-core/) - I'm not sure if this is the cause or not, or whether this is standard behaviour of a .net core application.

Can anybody hazard a guess as to what could be happening here and also let me know if this behaviour is expected?

Answer (score 0):

Obvious guess is that `ClassLibrary1` and `ClassLibrary2` are sitting somewhere within the `Kayta` project's directory.  They should at least be sitting in sibling directories.  e.g.

```
Kayta (Solution Directory)
  - Kayta (Web Project Directory
  - ClassLibrary1 (Library Directory)
  - ClassLibrary2 (Library Directory)
```

Instead of:

```
Kayta (Solution Directory)
  - Kayta (Web Project Directory
    - ClassLibrary1 (Library Directory)
    - ClassLibrary2 (Library Directory)
```

If this isn't the case though, then you may need to post what your directory structure is.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've tried creating new folders outside inside the mail solution folder for the new projects.. it adds the class libraries in to these folders but also adds the class library folder in to the web project. It's very strange. I'm led to believe it has something to do with the xproj file if I'm honest as it doesn't look like a standard project file. I'll update the question with the folder structure as you've asked.